# Call recordings and Call Logs on Zoho CRM mobile app

Tags: crm, zoho, zohobooks

Hi I  how do I use the Zoho CRM mobile app to record call logs and call recordings and be able to download them via the app. I would also like to know how to add another number that will be on another mobile device that does the call logs recording and call logs of the number. Thanks

Comment: You will need to connect with Zoho Telephony integration from any [integrated PBX vendors](https://www.zoho.com/telephony/providers-list/) to set up call recordings. You won't be able to do call recordings using mobile applications as of now. Although you could set up call log alert on Android devices.